# DeclareOption conditional does not seem to work

Tags: macros, errors, tex-core, conditionals

I can't seem to figure out why this isn't working. I'd like to set up an option for this package to allow for a preprint version (with no page range marked) and a final version with the page range included. The `\@firstpage` and `\@lastpage` commands are defined elsewhere.

From what I understand of TeX conditionals, I define a new choice, `\@final`, define it by default to be true. When the user invokes `\documentstyle[preprint]{package}` it should set `\@final` to false, and then later on define `\thepagerange` to be some text. If the preprint option is not used or is set to final, then `\@final` should be true (the default) and `\thepagerange` should be defined as shown.

The problem is that this does not seem to work. Regardless of whether I pass preprint or final, the compiler tosses out the errors:

```
./package.cls￼:388: Undefined control sequence.
￼l.388 \if@finaltrue

./package.cls:393: Extra \fi.
￼l.393 \fi

./package.cls:394: Undefined control sequence.
￼l.394 \if@finalfalse

./package.cls:396: Extra \fi.
￼l.396 \fi
```

Troublesome MWE here:

```
\newif\if@final
\@finaltrue

\DeclareOption{final}{\@finaltrue}
\DeclareOption{preprint}{\@finalfalse}

\ProcessOptions

\if@finaltrue
\def\thepagerange{%                                   
   \ifnum\@lastpage =0 {\ \bf ???} \else
   \ifnum\@lastpage = \@firstpage \ \thefirstpage\else
   \thefirstpage--\thelastpage \fi\fi}
\fi
\if@finalfalse
\def\thepagerange{xx--xx}
\fi
```

Comment: This is no MWE so far. It is  incomplete class code and no document that loads this class

Comment: Your code isn't compilable. But the conditional is `\if@final <true part> \else <false part> \fi` not `\if@finaltrue ...`.  Also `\bf` is a deprecated command and you shouldn't use it. Use `\bfseries` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define a conditional using  `\newif\if@final` the conditional itself is simply `\if@final`.  You set the conditional by using either `\@finaltrue` or `\@finalfalse`.

If you want to use the conditional then the syntax is:

```
\if@final
   <true part code>
\else
   <false part code>
\fi
```

You are trying to use `\if@finaltrue` (and later `\if@finalfalse`) and since those macros do not exist, you predictably get an "Undefined control sequence" errors (as your error shows.)

You also shouldn't use `\bf`, which is a deprecated command. Use `\bfseries` instead.